# How do I make my superview resize to match the size of its subviews with Autolayout?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I've got a `UIView` ("superview") that has a couple of `UILabels` as subviews, set up in Interface Builder. I've got Auto-Layout turned on to properly space all the labels in a list, one after another. This works well.

What I'm trying to do now is make it so that my Superview resizes vertically to match the height of all my labels and I can't quite figure out how to do this.

How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using visual layouts... so ignore the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints business.

This relies on the fact that the container view does NOT have any height constraints and it seems to rely on the spacing between views. The system will resize the view to match the requirements of the subviews.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        _labelOne = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _labelOne.text = @"Banana";
        _labelOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [_labelOne setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        _labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _labelTwo.text = @"Dinosaur";
        _labelTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        [_labelTwo setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [self addSubview:_labelOne];
        [self addSubview:_labelTwo];

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelOne, _labelTwo);
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_labelOne]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_labelTwo]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[_labelOne(30)]-15-[_labelTwo(30)]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm this is good, however the issue is the label heights can change, as they have multiple lines enabled (I guess I should have mentioned this in my question). Still trying to wrap my head around having that work, while maintaining a bottom padding.

Comment: You could change the fixed '30' heights I threw in there as an example for >=30, which would at least allow the expansion of the views.

Not 100% sure on how to trigger sizeToFit ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I know the basic idea is to have the intrinsic content size of your subviews drive the height of superview by making sure the content compression resistance and content hugging constraints in the vertical dimension for each subview are not being overridden by higher-priority constraints you have added.

Answer (score -2):

Try use the UIView method `sizeToFit`?

Comment: No idea, but I assume so. Try it and let us know :)